# javascript read number of hours worked

Tags: javascript

Write the JavaScript to read the number of hours worked from the user. Then write the JavaScript to calculate how much money the user made if they were paid $12/hour for the first 40 hours worked, and $18/hr for all hours worked over 40. Then use the alert() function to print the total amount to the user.

what code do I have to use

var  y = prompt("Enter a Value","");

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want us to help with your homework, you need to show some effort first. What have you tried so far? What obstacles have you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

Lol #OverComplicated. The answer is there just remake a better version and try your homework before being spoonfed.

```
var BarryScott =  {
  PricePerHour: 12,
  HoursWorkedByBarry: 0,
  PrintPayment: function() {

    if ( this.HoursWorkedByBarry > 40) {
      var RemainHours = this.HoursWorkedByBarry - 40;
      alert(this.PricePerHour * 40 + RemainHours * 18);
    } else {
      alert(this.PricePerHour * this.HoursWorkedByBarry);
    } 
  },
  AskHoursFromBarry: function() {
    this.HoursWorkedByBarry = prompt("Enter Hours you worked");
    this.PrintPayment();
  }
}


BarryScott.AskHoursFromBarry();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder and place your index.html and javascript code inside.
Run index.html .

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Im lazy to do my assignment</title>
          <script src = "billhours.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

billhours.js

```
var getInput = prompt("Enter Number of Hours worked");
var first40hrs = billHours(40, 12);
var over40hrs = billHours(getInput - 40, 18);
var totalSalary = first40hrs + over40hrs;

alert("Total Salary is "+totalSalary);

function billHours(hours, rate){
        return hours*rate;
}
//This function only works for hours 40 and above.
//It's your job to put conditional statements if hours is below 40. Keep Coding.
```